# $y'(x)=y^2-y$ and $y(0)=\frac 12$. Show that $y(x) \in (0,1)$ $\forall x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$y'(x)=y^2-y$ and $y(0)=\frac 12$. Show that $y(x) \in (0,1)$   $\forall x$

I have:

$\frac {dy}{dx}=y^2-y \Rightarrow \frac {dy}{y(y-1)}=dx \Rightarrow \int \frac{dy}{y(y-1)} = \int dx$

$\int \frac {dy}{y(y-1)} = \int \frac {1}{y-1}dy - \int \frac {1}{y} = ln|1-y|-ln|y|$

So we have:

$ln|\frac{1-y}{y}|=x+C \Rightarrow \frac {1-y}{y}=Ce^x$

$y(x)=\frac 1{Ce^x+1}$

$y(0)=\frac 12 \Rightarrow C=1 \Rightarrow y(x)=\frac 1{e^x+1}$

So we see that $y(x) \in (0,1) \forall x$.

Is this the right way to do this example? Also i have a question what happens when $y=0$, $y=1$ (line 3 when i divided by $y(y-1)$?

Comment: If $y\not=0,1$, so we have that $\frac{1}{y(y-1)}=\frac{1}{y-1}-\frac{1}{y}$. Also, note that $\ln\left| \frac{1-y}{y}\right|=x+c \implies \left|\frac{1-y}{y} \right|=Ce^{x}, \forall x\in \mathbf{R}.$